# biblatex and windicity: incollection editor before/after booktitle depending on using crossref or not

Tags: biblatex, windycity

We have two versions of a @incollection entries in our biblatex database.

**Version one (Crossref):**

```
@incollection{lobsinger_two_2013,
    title = {Two Cambridges: Models, Methods, Systems, and Expertise},
    pages = {652--85},
    shorttitle = {Two Cambridges}, 
    author = {Lobsinger, Mary Louise},
    crossref = {lobsinger_two_2013_main}
}

@collection{lobsinger_two_2013_main,
    location = {Cambridge, MA},
    title = {A Second Modernism: {MIT}, Architecture, and the “Techno-Social” Moment},
    publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    editor = {Dutta, Arindam},
    date = {2013},
    langid = {english},
}
```

**Version two (all data in one entry):**

```
@incollection{lobsinger_test,
    title = {Two Cambridges: Models, Methods, Systems, and Expertise},
    pages = {652--85},
    shorttitle = {Two Cambridges}, 
    author = {Lobsinger, Mary Louise},
    location = {Cambridge, MA},
    booktitle = {A Second Modernism: {MIT}, Architecture, and the “Techno-Social” Moment},
    publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    editor = {Dutta, Arindam},
    date = {2013},
    langid = {english}
}
```

I'm wondering why the two entries are laid out differently:

**Here's the output of version one - with Crossref:**

[image: version 1]

**Here's the output of version two - without Crossref:**

[image: version 2]

With crossrefs the editor ends up after the booktitle. Without crossref, the editor is in front of the booktitle.

The Question: Is there a possibility to change this to a consistent behaviour (in our case: editor after booktitle?). I searched for configuration options but could not find any.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That is behaviour is something I would call a bug. Even if you don't think it's a bug, it's still something the developer should know about, so I suggest you report it at https://github.com/brianchase/windycity/issues.

Comment: Thanks - Posted an issue. Since both styles are correct according to the chicago manual of style, I consider it more like a missing parameter. But yes - maybe in the end - inconsistent behavior is a probably a bug.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it below in the answers section and accept it. That way others can benefit from the answer more easily and people see that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Issuee resolved. This is intended and can be resolved with `editortype={booktitle}`. See https://github.com/brianchase/windycity/issues/22